# How to get a variable value file from laravel blade

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a hidden field in laravel blade.

```
 <input type="hidden" name="agencyid" value="{{Auth::user()->agency_id}}" />
```

How will i get the value of this variable "agencyid" and assign to another variable? Like

```
$agency=$agencyid;
```

Iam trying to pass this value to an external PHP file.

```
   <?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/core/agency_expiry.php?agency=$agency'); ?>
```

Iam new to laravel so exploring the same.

Comment: Inside controller?

Comment: Iam trying to pass this value ($agencyid) to an external php page.

Comment: i guess am asking some stupid question. :)

Comment: @SidMenon what is he purpose of `$agency` in here, you need to use `$agency` inside the php file .?

Comment: What do you mean by "pass this value to an external php file". If I am correctly guessing what you are trying to do, then you are doing it wrong. You shouldn't try to pass data to an external php file directly, you should catch the data in a controller and then play with the data as you desire.

Comment: hidden inputs usually go in a `<form>` and are submitted to a route for handling by laravel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the value by simply putting inside a php tag.

```
<?php $agency = Auth::user()->agency_id; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library:
https://github.com/ixudra/curl

```
use Ixudra\Curl\Facades\Curl;

public function externalLink(Request $request) {
    $agency = $request['agencyid'];
    $url = Curl::to( __DIR__..'/core/agency_expiry.php?agency='.$agency)->get();

    //now play with the return value
    dd($url);
}
```